# Clipping the bezier path in curve shape

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uibezierpath, curve

I using Swift to creating a custom button in a phone UI and need to clip the bottom of the button in the convex like shape.

[image: Like this]

The problem was it should be perfect and the bottom curve should match the bigger button

[image: Like this]

I tried different approaches but it's not getting the perfect result.

1. Using rounded corners

   ```
   if buttonDirection == 0 {
       path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners:[UIRectCorner.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: self.bounds.width/2, height: 0))
       path.close()  
   }
   ```
2. Create whole path without rounded curve using QuardCurve // still bottom part not inverse curve plus corner are also not smooth as 1

   ```
    if buttonDirection == 0 {
          //path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners:[UIRectCorner.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: self.bounds.width/2, height: 0))
         //path.close()
           let curve = UIBezierPath()
           curve.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height))
           curve.addLine(to:CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.bounds.width/3))
           curve.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width, y: self.bounds.width/3), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width/2, y: -5))
           curve.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width, y: self.bounds.height))
           curve.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width/2, y: self.bounds.width - 10))
           UIColor.black.setFill()
           curve.fill()
       }
   ```
3. Create the path from 1 and then just Clip QuardCurve

   ```
   if buttonDirection == 0 {
       path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners:[UIRectCorner.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: self.bounds.width/2, height: 0))
       path.close()
       path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height))
       path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width, y: self.bounds.height), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width/2, y: self.bounds.height/2))
       path.addClip()
       UIColor.black.setFill()
       path.fill()
   }
   ```

I tried many other things also but not getting the result, What I wanted is simply clip the bottom curve from the 1st path, Like how to cut one path from another (After reading apples doc I come to know I can use path.reverse() also )

here are all buttons in one pic and when you click the button say vol + its changes the colour

[image: All four buttons vol+, vol-, ch+,ch- and centre button(which itself is subdivided in five-part :-pc)]

**PS** Edited the original question, as images were confusing, and I found one solution but still want to know if there is a better solution with one path and smooth edges.

Comment: I read through your question, but I don't understand what you mean with "clip the inverse curve". Your image also shows tons of graphics, are you talking specifically about "how do I create a circle with another circle cut out of it"?

Comment: check Vol+ button in 4th image, do you see the curve at the bottom its cut in a circular at the bottom

Comment: If the only thing that mattes is the vol+ button in the 4th image, then remove the other images, and just show, with a clear, contrasting color scheme, that particular thing. Right now you're showing five images all with colours that are going to leave lots of folks going "my eyes are nowhere near good enough to see what this person's showing". Also good to show what you're going for, before explaining what you've tried.

Comment: actually, its all buttons vol+, vol-, ch +, ch - but thanks, will update the question :-)

Comment: Rather than using curves, why not use arcs? You know the radii of your circles, so working with actual circular arcs would be a heck of a lot easier than manually approximating good curvatures? Just use single, 2pi arcs centered on your main circle, at the appropriate radius, as your clipping path and that should be all you need to do?

Comment: I tried arc first but actually smaller buttons are 1/4 the radius of the bigger button so it will work even if screen size change and less calculation and with arc, there were more calculation, centre, radius, endpoint and start point, So I went with quardCurve

Comment: and your website https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/ on Bezier curve is great :-)  Is there any performance issue over one other? quardCurve is only using one cp and arc I think do it internally but still use cp as center, right ?

Comment: You shouldn't need endpoint and startpoint for the clipping path: you're clipping  off an entire circle, so those are both just `(center x + radius, center y)`. There is rarely a performance difference between quadratic vs. cubic in terms of drawing (cubic might take longer to evaluate, but measured in nanoseconds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below method worked but if someone has better solution do post. 
Basically what I am doing here is first clipping the whole button with the bottom part as convex, using addLines and Quardcurve in the bottom and after that creating new path using bezier roundedRect initialization with top-right and top-left corner.

```
if buttonDirection == 0 {
     let curve = UIBezierPath()
     curve.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height))
     curve.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
     curve.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width, y: 0))
     curve.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width, y: self.bounds.height))
     curve.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width/2, y: self.bounds.height - self.bounds.height/4))
     curve.close()
     curve.addClip()
     path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners:[UIRectCorner.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: self.bounds.width/2, height: 0))
     path.close()
}
```